# PRAISE BE UNTO HE

Tags: riddle, poetry

He is everywhere, in the heavens and Earth.
He cannot be seen.
He can lift you into the sky and bring you gently down.
He can take many forms.
He can help heal.
He can help kill, yet
He is noble.
He can help create and
He can help destroy.

Comment: I, for one second, thought this was Ask Ubuntu and I stumbled upon a horrible misspelling of Ubuntu.

Comment: I am not sure. Gene Hart is the actual author, I just modified it a bit.

Comment: @Marko Please note that there are strict rules about plagiarism on this site.  If the puzzle is not yours, it's important to indicate where it came from and/or who authored it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is referring to

> Helium (chemical symbol `He`)

He is everywhere, in the heavens and Earth.

> It is abundant in stars and throughout space.  It is also mined from within the earth.

He cannot be seen.

> It is invisible in its (natural) gaseous form.

He can lift you into the sky and bring you gently down.

> It is used in balloons and dirigibles to lift people/things into the sky.

He can take many forms.

> It can be solid, liquid, or gas.  It also has different isotopes.

He can help heal.

> It is used in MRI machines in hospitals.

He can help kill, yet

> You won't be able to breathe in a room full of helium.

He is noble.

> It is one of the noble gases.

He can help create

> It is used to create rocket fuel.

He can help destroy.

> Liquid helium is extremely cold, and could destroy many things due to its temperature.

Comment: Damn, @GentlePurpleRain, you are too fast.  +1

Comment: create probably refering to something like the [triple alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process)

Comment: To kill might refer to alpha particles (helium nucleus) which can kill if inhaled/ingested (ie radon).  To create might refer to welding - which often uses helium.

Comment: I'd like to add that every sentence starts with the answer lel